# how to solve ERROR: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm using a MySql database and I have created a field in my table named `ID` which is set to auto-increment and not null. However, I'm receiving an error as:

> ERROR: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key

I have given `datakeynames="ID"` in my `GridView`. Is there something wrong in this?

When I put a breakpoint at the point of the query and directly insert data to `mysql` it is inserted without any problem.

Here is my `GridView` declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUploadedFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="7" DataKeyNames="ID" ..>
```

And my SQL statement:

```
INSERT into tbluploadedfilesdetail (FileType,FileName,FileExt,FilePath,WebUrl) VALUES (...)
```

it gives this error at myobjcon.open() statement

```
MySqlConnection objMyCon1 = new MySqlConnection();
objMyCon1.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(getSQL1, objMyCon1);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
objMyCon1.Close();
dbLoad();
```

Comment: As a tip, check this article that is a great guide on how to write questions to get good answers here on SO: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints Writing a good question is an art in itself :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At first you have connect to your DB so you need to create a `ConnectionString` then your code will work,

It means that you are on the air and trying to acdcess a parachute that is not in your back. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we finally got to where we could see some code, so note this:

```
MySqlConnection objMyCon1 = new MySqlConnection(); 
objMyCon1.Open();
```

What is objMyCon1 supposed to open?  You haven't given your object any information about what it's supposed to do.  It's a MySqlConnection, sure, but it needs to know where your database is before it can connect.

Answer (score 0):

You create `MySqlConnection objMyCon1 = new MySqlConnection();` and trying to open, but you need to specify connection string I think(Found something familiar [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=564167)).

Comment: I believe the connection string is omitted, if you read the question again you'll find the text "When I put a breakpoint..." which suggest this error occurs when in release mode but not while debugging.